# I have two navs that I want to be on the same line at the top of my header

Tags: html, css

At the top of my header, I have two navs. Right now, they are on top of each other, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwJmz.png).

I want them to be side. It seems like all I would need to do is set the nav elements to display: inline;, but it isn't working. I've also tried doing float left and float right. I've tried tons of options and done some research and feel really lost here.

Here is the html.

```
<body>
<header>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li>HOME</li>
      <li>WORK</li>
      <li>ABOUT</li>
      <li>CONTACT</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><img src="images/youtube.png" alt=""></li>
      <li><img src="images/twitter.png" alt=""></li>
      <li><img src="images/facebook.png" alt=""></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: First of all the above code doesn't even work!

Answer (score 1):

The first mistake you have is that your current code doesn't work with Bootstrap Navbar. The `navbar-right` class helps you to make it go right. You need to have something like this for two navbars on the same line:

```
<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>HOME</li>
        <li>WORK</li>
        <li>ABOUT</li>
        <li>CONTACT</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><img src="images/youtube.png" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="images/twitter.png" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="images/facebook.png" alt=""></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

In case if you aren't using Bootstrap, then for your custom CSS, you need to give `float: left` and `float: right`. I have reformatted your HTML by changing removing the duplicate `<nav>` and using a new class `nav-right`:

```css
.navbar {overflow: hidden;}
.nav, .nav li {display: block; margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}
.nav li {display: inline-block;}
.nav {float: left;}
.nav.nav-right {float: right;}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li>HOME</li>
      <li>WORK</li>
      <li>ABOUT</li>
      <li>CONTACT</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav nav-right">
      <li><img src="images/youtube.png" alt=""></li>
      <li><img src="images/twitter.png" alt=""></li>
      <li><img src="images/facebook.png" alt=""></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: inline-block;`  to `nav`, and if you want the list items aligned horzontally, also add `display: inline-block;` to `nav li`:

```css
nav {
display: inline-block;
}
nav li {
display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li>HOME</li>
      <li>WORK</li>
      <li>ABOUT</li>
      <li>CONTACT</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><img src="images/youtube.png" alt="">A</li>
      <li><img src="images/twitter.png" alt="">B</li>
      <li><img src="images/facebook.png" alt="">C</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

If you meant to place the left and right, you can put `inline-block` only on the `li` elements and put `float: left` on the first and `float: right` on the second `nav`

```css
nav:first-of-type {
 float: left;
}
nav:last-of-type {
 float: right;
}
nav:first-of-type ul {
 float: left;
 padding-left: 0;
}
nav li {
display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li>HOME</li>
      <li>WORK</li>
      <li>ABOUT</li>
      <li>CONTACT</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><img src="images/youtube.png" alt="">A</li>
      <li><img src="images/twitter.png" alt="">B</li>
      <li><img src="images/facebook.png" alt="">C</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use flexbox for that.

```
header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

This makes both children of `header` to be on the same line and justifies them to be space between them what makes them to be on the edges which is what you want.

You also need to style these two children, but it's up to you.